# Is declaring a namespace inside a tag makes this tag use the namespace as the default namespace?

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces, schema

So given the following xml, does the ticket element use the declared xmlns:mes1 namespace or does it belong to the default namespace? (note: in the full original message the xmlns namespace is never declared)

```
<Ticket xmlns:mes1="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/116/MessageData">
    <RequestProcessResult xmlns:tic="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/116/Ticket">
        <ResultCode xmlns:err="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/116/ErrInfo">11</ResultCode>
        <ResultDescription xmlns:err="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/116/ErrInfo">23503 : INSERT</ResultDescription>
        <ResultData xmlns:err="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/116/ErrInfo">CONTEXT:  SQL</ResultData>
    </RequestProcessResult>
</Ticket>
```

My understanding is that the Ticket and its nested elements are all in the default namespace and the declared namespaces are never used.

But this fragment comes from a serious information system though previously a message from it contained a default namespace declaration in the soap header and the part I'm intrested in was like this (note the namespaces):

```
<mes1:Ticket xmlns:mes1="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/116/MessageData">
    <tic:RequestProcessResult xmlns:tic="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/116/Ticket">
        <err:ResultCode xmlns:err="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/116/ErrInfo">0</err:ResultCode>
        <err:ResultData xmlns:err="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/116/ErrInfo">ID_6ac73577-1840-4110-8f24-33ae4760dfcf</err:ResultData>
    </tic:RequestProcessResult>
</mes1:Ticket>
```

Ultimately received packets as in the first example can not be handled correctly with the following code (java)

```
public ImportResponse(BaseMessageType msg) {
    super(msg);
    responseMessageData = ((ResponseMessageType) ((JAXBElement) messageData.getAppData().getAny().get(0)).getValue()).getResponseMessageData();
}
```

producing exception 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement

It is either incoming messages are not created correctly then the source of the messages should be informed or the code should be tweaked to handle this new format for me.

Comment: In the first sample the `Ticket` element is in no namespace.

Comment: That's what I think too. Modifying the original message by adding the prefixes to the elements leads to the correct deserialization. Thank you for  the confirmation.